# Connect remote build server to local beaglebone

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Hi so I have researched this question to death and still can't seen to get things working, any help is much appreciated.

Currently I have a home server that handles building all my binaries for my beaglebone black.  I like it very much, I can ssh in from any computer and all my local VIM and tmuxinator settings along with the arm cross compiler tools are already set up.

My issue arises when I try to debug.  My local set up is build on server then connect to a gdbserver running on the beaglebone for debugging an executable.  The issue is remotely, I have my laptop which I use to SSH to my remote build server, but my beaglebone is connected to my laptop.  Is it possible to create a tunnel from my laptop to my remote build server so it can ssh into my beaglebone for loading the built executable for example?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make a reverse tunnel (initiated from your laptop, because it has access to the beaglebone) which opens a port on your build server that is tied to the SSH-port of the beaglebone. As long as you keep that tunnel alive, you would be able to access the beaglebone via SSH directly from your buildserver, which is what you want to achieve if I understand your question correctly?

From your laptop, open a terminal and make a reverse tunnel from your buildserver to your beaglebone

```
    ssh -R 9876:beaglebone:22 server
```

This opens a port 9876 (pick a number that is convenient for you) on the server and that connects to the SSH-server port of the *beaglebone* address (assuming it is default 22). Keep this session open.

Now, as a user on the server, you should be able to access the *beaglebone* through the tunnel by making an SSH connection to the newly created port, i.e.,

```
    ssh -p 9876 localhost
```

I've used this approach before, but have no means to test it right now. Please let me know if this is what you were after. I think there are SSH flags to make the reverse tunnel without taking a terminal, but I never cared to try that.